# How can I unit test my Swift application that uses Firebase Authentication for most views?

Tags: swift, unit-testing, firebase, xctest

I have built an application in Swift using Firebase where most of the functionality is only accessible once a user is logged in. For example, I have a budget page that fetches the event budget from the database but this can only be done once a user is logged in.

Is anyone able to advise how I can test the features that require a call to the database? I would have thought I needed to a sign in a user in my test class and then use those details to test my controllers but each time it returns nil? I have even tried to run my login view controller in my test class to authenticate a user but that doesn't work either.

Thank you!

Answer (score 4):

For Unit tests it is best if you eliminate all outside dependencies. One way that I prefer to do this, especially with any sort of network or database, is to create a Mock object and inject the mock object in instead of using the actual network module or database. This will involve some refactoring for dependency injection and abstracting your manager for your Firebase into a protocol that can be mocked.
With a MockFirebase you can have all of the "authentication" without having to use your network or hit the actual database.

If your Firebase manager is set up as a Singleton then a good resource to use for making the Mock of it is:

https://medium.com/@johnsundell/testing-swift-code-that-uses-system-singletons-in-3-easy-steps-89f4884cd325

For information on mocking in general here is another link:

https://www.swiftbysundell.com/posts/mocking-in-swift